# How to partition an encrypted disk

Tags: partitioning, 13.10, encryption, lvm

I've installed Ubuntu 13.10 and formatted my whole HDD ,and i chose to encrypt the disk and it automatically chose the LVM option (and put it as a logical partition)
now after Ubuntu installed i tried to repartition the disk thru Live CD put `GPartition` gave me it's an encrypted partition and it can't be resized ,
i want to put the system's files and the home folder on partition and my private files on another one 
Any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to format from scratch and then encrypt again.
Anyway, as suggested by David Foerster, it is possible to resize encrypted partitions from the command line.

You should find all information here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions

Comment: i can not do that now after installing the OS and the packages it would be too difficult

Comment: I disagree. Encrypted partitions can be resized almost like regular partitions. That "almost" is the reason why none of the common graphical partition managers can deal with them though and one has to perform the steps on the command line. -1